# Would the angular acceleration be the same but in the opposite direction?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

The acceleration of point B of a on a rigid body would be:
[image]

Problem what im confused about is if you were to find the acceleration of A, would alpha be the same magnitude but in the opposite direction?

Image below shows what happens when you fix the point A (the rotation about A), the direction of the angular acceleration is anticlockwise. What happens if you fix the point B and do a rotation anticlockwise, would the angular acceleration be the same but just clockwise?

[image]